# Import Profile Product Review import/export

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-review-import-export.html for importing prodcuts review.

I've exported review from one Magento site and I'm trying to import on another website.

While importing products it's show message "Processed 0% 0/1 records" and keep it showing, No process in importing products.

[Importing Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCkkB.png)

I've changed my table prefix in "app/code/local/MK/Reviewexport/Model/Convert/Adapter/Reviewimport.php" but still nothing happening.

Waited too long but it keep showing me "Processed 0% 0/1 records" I've too many reviews and so it was not working I've removed all reviews from CSV and kept only one review.

This extension is created by : https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/599/mufaddal

Comment: Its better to contact the devoloper using magento connect.

Comment: Developer not replying, Tried doing personal email as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways I've resolved the issue by making custom script for importing reviews which is exported by that mentioned extension.

Here is a code

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();

    $fileLocation = "var/import/import_review.csv";
    $fp = fopen($fileLocation, 'r');
    $count = 1;

    while($data = fgetcsv($fp)){
        if($count > 1){
            //intiate requirement varibles
            $_createdAt     = $data[0];
            $_sku           = $data[1];
            $_catalog       = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $_productId     = $_catalog->getIdBySku($_sku);
            $_statusId      = $data[2];
            $_title         = $data[3];
            $_detail        = $data[4];
            $_customerId    = NULL;
            $_nickname      = $data[5];

            //load magento review model and assign values
            $review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
            $review->setCreatedAt($_createdAt); //created date and time
            $review->setEntityPkValue($_productId);//product id
            $review->setStatusId($_statusId); // status id
            $review->setTitle($_title); // review title
            $review->setDetail($_detail); // review detail
            $review->setEntityId(1); // leave it 1
            $review->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()); // store id
            $review->setCustomerId($_customerId); //null is for administrator
            $review->setNickname($_nickname); //customer nickname
            $review->setReviewId($review->getId());//set current review id
            $review->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));//store id's
            $review->save();
            $review->aggregate();

            //set review ratings
            if($data[7]){
                $arr_data = explode("@",$data[7]);
                if(!empty($arr_data)) {
                    foreach($arr_data as $each_data) {
                        $arr_rating = explode(":",$each_data);
                        if($arr_rating[1] != 0) {
                            Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                            ->setRatingId($arr_rating[0])
                            ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                            ->setCustomerId($_customerId)
                            ->addOptionVote($arr_rating[1], $_productId);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $review->aggregate();
            }
        }
       // if($count == 5){
       //       die("total $count reviews are imported!");
       //  }
        $count++;
    }

    echo "total $count reviews are imported!";
?>
```